# Looping through multiple joined tables with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm working on a site where I am outputting gathered data from multiple tables which the first two hold basic information and the last two hold properties and images. Currently I have worked my way through a couple lines of code which return the values of the tables and output **most** of the data I require to display when finally appending it to the html. The few issues I am having is replication issues which I understand comes with the territory of inner joins. My php file has filtered out the duplications to an extent but fails on of of two arrays which I am trying to make and thats the image array or the features array. So I have

```
if (isset($_POST['getAll'])) {

$sortBy = $_POST['getAll'];

$sqlQuery = "
SELECT 
    u.user_id, 
    u.user_username, 
    pr.project_id, 
    pr.created_date, 
    pr.closing_date, 
    pr.prize, 
    pr.project_desc, 
    pr.project_title, 
    pr.state, 
    prr.room_id, 
    prr.room_name, 
    prr.room_type, 
    prp.prop_id, 
    prp.comment_extra_details, 
    prp.feature_name, 
    prf.caption, 
    prf.filename, 
    prf.filetype, 
    prf.file_id,
     prf.public_name 
FROM users AS u 
    INNER JOIN projects as pr ON u.user_id = pr.creator_id 
    INNER JOIN project_rooms as prr ON prr.project_id = pr.project_id 
    INNER JOIN project_properties as prp ON prp.room_id = prr.room_id 
    INNER JOIN project_files as prf ON prf.room_id = prp.room_id
WHERE 
    state = 1 
ORDER BY 
    `created_date` DESC";
}

$result = $conn->query($sqlQuery);

$proj_id = 0;
$room_id = 0;
$prop_id = 0;
$file_id = 0;

$projects = array();
$rooms = array();
$features = array();
$images = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

if ($proj_id != $row["project_id"]) {

    $details = array(
        "user_id" => $row["user_id"],
        "username" => $row["user_username"],
        "project_id" => $row["project_id"],
        "created_date" => $row["created_date"],
        "closing_date" => $row["closing_date"],
        "prize" => $row["prize"],
        "project_desc" => $row["project_desc"],
        "project_title" => $row["project_title"],
        "rooms" => array()
    );

    $proj_id = $row["project_id"];
    $projects[] = $details;
    $info = array();

}

if ($room_id != $row["room_id"]) {

        $info = array(
                "room_id" => $row["room_id"],
                "room_name" => $row["room_name"],
                "room_type" => $row["room_type"],
                "comment_extra_details" => $row["comment_extra_details"],
                "caption" => $row["caption"],
                "feats" => array(),
                "images" => array()
        );

        $room_id = $row["room_id"];
        $rooms[] = $info;
        $feat = array();
    $counter = sizeof($projects) - 1;
    $projects[$counter]["rooms"] = $info;


}

//This is giving me the trouble
//if ($prop_id != $row["prop_id"]) {

//  $feat = array(
//    "feature_name" => $row["feature_name"]
//);

//$prop_id = $row["prop_id"];
//$features[] = $feat;

//$projects[$counter]["rooms"]["feats"] = $features;

//}


else if ($file_id != $row["file_id"]) {

    $img[] = array(
        "filename" => $row["filename"],
        "filetype" => $row["filetype"],
        "file_id" => $row["file_id"],
        "public_name" => $row["public_name"]
    );

    $file_id = $row["file_id"];
    $images = $img;

    $projects[$counter]["rooms"]["images"] = $images;
}

}
```

which outputs this:

[My Semi Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJpKs.png)

when I throw this code chunk in there, which loops through my features rows

```
if ($prop_id != $row["prop_id"]) {

  $feat = array(
    "feature_name" => $row["feature_name"]
);

$prop_id = $row["prop_id"];
$features[] = $feat;

$projects[$counter]["rooms"]["feats"] = $features;

}
```

I get this undesired output, which I can only assume is due to the logic flow and the loop ending:

[The bad...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLk1c.png)

Now I know that there is definitely not 15 features, there are 5, and 3 images but I can't seem to isolate one or the other without features or images breaking somehow.

EDIT -- I have included a visualization of my table data that the query returns, I hope this helps.

```
+---------+---------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+------------------+-------------------+------------+---------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------+
| user_id | user_username | project_id |    created_date     |    closing_date     | prize |   project_desc   |   project_title   |   state    | room_id | room_name |  room_type  | prop_id | comment_extra_details | feature_name | caption |                   filename                    |  filetype  | file_id | public_name |
+---------+---------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+------------------+-------------------+------------+---------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------+
|      10 | CalebB        |         27 | 2016-04-06 21:38:00 | 2016-04-27 21:38:00 |  5500 | heres some janks | Just another test | qualifying |      26 | NULL      | Family Room |      42 | NULL                  | Decor        |         | b59b3bb7cac73e8cbba0f68795aba254_1459993038.p | image/png  |      38 | NULL        |
|      10 | CalebB        |         27 | 2016-04-06 21:38:00 | 2016-04-27 21:38:00 |  5500 | heres some janks | Just another test | qualifying |      26 | NULL      | Family Room |      43 | NULL                  | Furniture    |         | b59b3bb7cac73e8cbba0f68795aba254_1459993038.p | image/png  |      38 | NULL        |
|      10 | CalebB        |         27 | 2016-04-06 21:38:00 | 2016-04-27 21:38:00 |  5500 | heres some janks | Just another test | qualifying |      26 | NULL      | Family Room |      44 | NULL                  | Paint        |         | b59b3bb7cac73e8cbba0f68795aba254_1459993038.p | image/png  |      38 | NULL        |
|      10 | CalebB        |         27 | 2016-04-06 21:38:00 | 2016-04-27 21:38:00 |  5500 | heres some janks | Just another test | qualifying |      26 | NULL      | Family Room |      45 | NULL                  | Flooring     |         | b59b3bb7cac73e8cbba0f68795aba254_1459993038.p | image/png  |      38 | NULL        |
|      10 | CalebB        |         27 | 2016-04-06 21:38:00 | 2016-04-27 21:38:00 |  5500 | heres some janks | Just another test | qualifying |      26 | NULL      | Family Room |      46 | NULL                  | Apolstery    |         | b59b3bb7cac73e8cbba0f68795aba254_1459993038.p | image/png  |      38 | NULL        |
|      10 | CalebB        |         27 | 2016-04-06 21:38:00 | 2016-04-27 21:38:00 |  5500 | heres some janks | Just another test | qualifying |      26 | NULL      | Family Room |      42 | NULL                  | Decor        |         | 21c3b842752b3866a37912048e6d0bbd_1459993053.j | image/jpeg |      39 | NULL        |
|      10 | CalebB        |         27 | 2016-04-06 21:38:00 | 2016-04-27 21:38:00 |  5500 | heres some janks | Just another test | qualifying |      26 | NULL      | Family Room |      43 | NULL                  | Furniture    |         | 21c3b842752b3866a37912048e6d0bbd_1459993053.j | image/jpeg |      39 | NULL        |
|      10 | CalebB        |         27 | 2016-04-06 21:38:00 | 2016-04-27 21:38:00 |  5500 | heres some janks | Just another test | qualifying |      26 | NULL      | Family Room |      44 | NULL                  | Paint        |         | 21c3b842752b3866a37912048e6d0bbd_1459993053.j | image/jpeg |      39 | NULL        |
|      10 | CalebB        |         27 | 2016-04-06 21:38:00 | 2016-04-27 21:38:00 |  5500 | heres some janks | Just another test | qualifying |      26 | NULL      | Family Room |      45 | NULL                  | Flooring     |         | 21c3b842752b3866a37912048e6d0bbd_1459993053.j | image/jpeg |      39 | NULL        |
|      10 | CalebB        |         27 | 2016-04-06 21:38:00 | 2016-04-27 21:38:00 |  5500 | heres some janks | Just another test | qualifying |      26 | NULL      | Family Room |      46 | NULL                  | Apolstery    |         | 21c3b842752b3866a37912048e6d0bbd_1459993053.j | image/jpeg |      39 | NULL        |
|      10 | CalebB        |         27 | 2016-04-06 21:38:00 | 2016-04-27 21:38:00 |  5500 | heres some janks | Just another test | qualifying |      26 | NULL      | Family Room |      42 | NULL                  | Decor        |         | 5b4645c9ee88704eae9a12e422d86ba2_1459993063.j | image/jpeg |      40 | NULL        |
|      10 | CalebB        |         27 | 2016-04-06 21:38:00 | 2016-04-27 21:38:00 |  5500 | heres some janks | Just another test | qualifying |      26 | NULL      | Family Room |      43 | NULL                  | Furniture    |         | 5b4645c9ee88704eae9a12e422d86ba2_1459993063.j | image/jpeg |      40 | NULL        |
|      10 | CalebB        |         27 | 2016-04-06 21:38:00 | 2016-04-27 21:38:00 |  5500 | heres some janks | Just another test | qualifying |      26 | NULL      | Family Room |      44 | NULL                  | Paint        |         | 5b4645c9ee88704eae9a12e422d86ba2_1459993063.j | image/jpeg |      40 | NULL        |
|      10 | CalebB        |         27 | 2016-04-06 21:38:00 | 2016-04-27 21:38:00 |  5500 | heres some janks | Just another test | qualifying |      26 | NULL      | Family Room |      45 | NULL                  | Flooring     |         | 5b4645c9ee88704eae9a12e422d86ba2_1459993063.j | image/jpeg |      40 | NULL        |
|      10 | CalebB        |         27 | 2016-04-06 21:38:00 | 2016-04-27 21:38:00 |  5500 | heres some janks | Just another test | qualifying |      26 | NULL      | Family Room |      46 | NULL                  | Apolstery    |         | 5b4645c9ee88704eae9a12e422d86ba2_1459993063.j | image/jpeg |      40 | NULL        |
+---------+---------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+------------------+-------------------+------------+---------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------+
```

Any help here or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated

Comment: according to your model, INNER JOIN project_files as prf ON prf.room_id = prp.room_id should refer to prr.room_id instead of prp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both @user3802077 and @jeff, I finally isolated my code and got the return I wanted.

This is the resulting code:

```
$sqlQuery = "
SELECT 
     u.user_id, 
     u.user_username, 
     pr.project_id, 
     pr.created_date, 
     pr.closing_date, 
     pr.prize, 
     pr.project_desc, 
     pr.project_title, 
     pr.state, 
     prr.room_id, 
     prr.room_name, 
     prr.room_type, 
     prp.prop_id, 
     prp.comment_extra_details,
     prp.feature_name 
FROM users AS u 
     INNER JOIN projects as pr ON u.user_id = pr.creator_id 
     INNER JOIN project_rooms as prr ON prr.project_id = pr.project_id 
     INNER JOIN project_properties as prp ON prp.room_id = prr.room_id 
WHERE 
     state = ? 
ORDER BY 
     pr.created_date DESC";



$result = $conn->prepare($sqlQuery);
$result->execute(array('qualifying'));

$proj_id = 0;
$room_id = 0;
$file_id = 0;

$projects = array();
$rooms = array();
$files = array();
$properties = array();
$images = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    if ($proj_id != $row["project_id"]) {
        $rooms = array();
        $files = array();
        $properties = array();
        $projects[] = array(
            "user_id" => $row["user_id"],
            "username" => $row["user_username"],
            "project_id" => $row["project_id"],
            "created_date" => $row["created_date"],
            "closing_date" => $row["closing_date"],
            "prize" => $row["prize"],
            "project_desc" => $row["project_desc"],
            "project_title" => $row["project_title"],
            "rooms" => array()
        );

    $rooms[] = array(
        "room_id" => $row["room_id"],
        "room_name" => $row["room_name"],
        "room_type" => $row["room_type"],
        "comment_extra_details" => $row["comment_extra_details"],
        "files" => array(),
        "properties" => array()
    );

    $rooms[0]["properties"][] = array(
        "feature_name" => $row["feature_name"]
    );

    $f = "SELECT * FROM project_files where room_id = ?";
    $result2 = $conn->prepare($f);
    $result2->execute(array($row['room_id']));



    while ($rowF = $result2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $rooms[0]['files'][] = array(
            "filename" => $rowF["filename"],
            "filetype" => $rowF["filetype"],
            "file_id" => $rowF["file_id"],
            "caption" => $rowF["caption"],
            "public_name" => $rowF["public_name"]
        );

    }

    $proj_id = $row["project_id"];
    $counter = sizeof($projects) - 1;
    $projects[$counter]["rooms"] = $rooms;

    } else {

        $rooms[0]["properties"][] = array(
            "feature_name" => $row["feature_name"]
        );
        $counter = sizeof($projects) - 1;
        $projects[$counter]["rooms"] = $rooms;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet I'll say that my suspicion is you have a Cartesian join.

There may be additional identifiers in those tables that make up the relationships.

For instance it seems like you're getting all project properties for all projects in that room whereas I assume you want only projects associated to that user id.

Add your table structures for better assistance

Edit:
After seeing the table structure it looks like you may have to include one additional table in the join. But to debug this, you could start including more data in the select and view the results until you find the problem columns that you'd have to use in the job conditions.

For now give this a shot:

```
    FROM users AS u
Inner join project_submissions as ps on
u.user_id = ps.user_id

INNER JOIN projects as pr ON u.user_id = pr.creator_id
And pr.project_id = ps.project_id
 INNER JOIN project_rooms as prr ON prr.project_id = pr.project_id
INNER JOIN project_properties as prp ON prp.room_id = prr.room_id
INNER JOIN project_files as prf ON prf.room_id = prp.room_id
```

Comment: Sorry, i replied to the wrong post, my DB model is screened here -> [link]http://www.calebbear.com/Images/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-07%20at%208.39.07%20PM.png

Comment: I gave this a quick try I'm not seeing anything return on the query. But for now I need to take a break- I've been at this thing for far too long today. I'll try some things tomorrow when I have the chance.

Comment: Fair enough. Next I'd suggest to pull a select from each of the tables to see where the Cartesian is coming from. Use the join condition in your where clause and go through them one at a time. You'll see the any instance of a table that returns many results on your join condition and can identify from those single select queries anything coming in that you don't expect. From that find the unique identifier for each table and add that to your join conditions.

Comment: Actually now I'm not so sure this is a Cartesian return. If you run your query in a sql editor do you get the table you're expecting or are there extra records?

Comment: I actually get everything I want: The User_Id, Username, Project_id, dates, prize, description, the state, room ID, the room name, room type,   prop_id, comment_extra_details, feature_name, caption, filename, filetype, file_id and public_name. That's all good there, so the issue I seem to be having is when returning this information- I understand there will be duplications, for example- i have 1 project : 1 room, then 1 room : m properties and 1 room : m images. so this returns me project_id 10 => property_id 42, 43, 44, 45 and then on that file_id 38, 39, 40. Con't

Comment: so when looping through to make an array of objects with this information, I'm trying to strip out the duplicates so that i have something that looks like this

`0 =>"basic details": "all the simple fields that have no duplications"...
    "rooms": " "feats" =>
                           0 =>'feat1'' 
                           1 =>'feat2'
                     "images" =>'
                           0 =>'img1 ''`

. At one point i thought it could have been my query, but I am getting the correct results.

Comment: I'll be discussion this with someone shortly, they we're working with me on this. I'll post my findings shortly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your room's feature array does not seem well defined.
`$projects[$counter]["rooms"]["feats"].`

I would set it after $projects[$counter]["rooms"] = $info;

```
$projects[$counter]["rooms"] = $info;
$projects[$counter]["rooms"]["feats"] = array();
```

Then use it in the prop branch

```
if ($prop_id != $row["prop_id"]) {

  $projects[$counter]["rooms"]["feats"][] = array(
    "feature_name" => $row["feature_name"]
  );

  $prop_id = $row["prop_id"];
}
```